# Tooltip inside TextInput label is not working. Material-UI + React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use an Outlined style of a [TextField](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) who's label must contain a [tooltip](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#tooltip) icon with some text
[image: Design]

Please refer to [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-7qyr6) for a live demo

**Code excerpt:**

```
const IconWithTooltip = () => (
  <Tooltip title="Text explaining stuff">
    <HelpIcon />
  </Tooltip>
);

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="with-label">
          FormControl with label
          <IconWithTooltip />
        </InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          id="with-label"
          startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <TextField
        label={
          <div>
            TextFiled
            <IconWithTooltip />
          </div>
        }
        variant="outlined"
      />
      Just icon with tooltop
      <IconWithTooltip />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Problem:**
When hovering over the (?) icon tooltip does not appear. I have tried coding the input in 2 different ways using FormControl and TextInput but none works. Am i missing something?

Comment: Your issue is with 'pointer-events: none' CSS inside of class .MuiInputLabel-outlined. Update it as per your need and it should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated by Nimmi in a comment, this is due to `pointer-events: none` in the [CSS for the label](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.4/packages/material-ui/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js#L73).

Changing this in the manner shown below does allow the tooltip to work, **but you should NOT do this**. This causes the label to be clickable. When `pointer-events` is `none`, a click on the label passes through to the input and causes it to receive focus. When `pointer-events` is `auto`, the click stops on the label and does not bring focus to the input.

You may want to look into leveraging helper text (shown below the input) as a place to incorporate the tooltip.

```
      <TextField
        InputLabelProps={{ style: { pointerEvents: "auto" } }}
        label={
          <div>
            TextFiled
            <IconWithTooltip />
          </div>
        }
        variant="outlined"
        type="text"
      />
```

[image: Edit Material UI]

Related documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Thanks for the usability tip. Definitely worth experimenting with text helper.

Comment: If you want tooltip inside `standard` variant too, add `zIndex: 500` to styles to make it work (500 is example, just add some high value).

Comment: how can still show tootip and clickable label to focus input both?

Comment: In situation input have required, then the symbol * will show in break line. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the InputLabelProps and make the tooltip work in the input adornment with the tooltip PopperProps:

```
                  <Tooltip
                    title="Tooltip message"
                    arrow
                    PopperProps={{
                      disablePortal: true,
                      popperOptions: {
                        positionFixed: true,
                        modifiers: {
                          preventOverflow: {
                            enabled: true,
                            boundariesElement: 'window'
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }}
                  >
                    <Info color="error" />
                  </Tooltip>
```